# Ul Li tag Can't be Right Aligned

Tags: html, css

I am trying to left align logo and right align the ul li tag. I am using float but strangely the code is not working and I have no idea why it is not getting right aligned. Please take a look -

the problem is i think i have used the same code elsewhere and it seems to be working perfectly but this time around for some unknown reason it is mot working.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}



/*
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
*/


body {
font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
}

.head {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto; 
 padding: 0px;
 background-color: #855fa8; 
}

.menu {
  width: 1020px;
  margin: 0 auto; 
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden; 
  padding-top: 20px;
}

 .left-menu {
   width: 15%;
   float: left;
 }
 
  .left-menu img {
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
  }
  
 
 
 .right-menu {
   width: 70%; 
   float: right; 
 }







/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
 list-style-type:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 position: absolute;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
 display:inline-block;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 1px;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
 display:block;
 min-width:80px;
 height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 50px;
 font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
 background: #19c589;
}

/*Style for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a {
 background: #f3f3f3;
 color: #2f3036;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
}

/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a:hover {
 background: #19c589;
 color: #fff;
}

/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
li ul {
 display: none;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
li ul li {
 display: block;
 float: none;
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
 width: auto;
 min-width: 100px;
 padding: 0 20px;
}

/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
 display: block;
}

/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 background: #19c589;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px 0;
 display: none;
}

/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
    display: block;
}


/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
 /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
 ul {
  position: static;
  display: none;
 }
 /*Create vertical spacing*/
 li {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
 }
 /*Make all menu links full width*/
 ul li, li a {
  width: 100%;
 }
 /*Display 'show menu' link*/
 .show-menu {
  display:block;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="head">

   <div class="menu">
            
                   <div class="left-menu">                   
                        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/MvTUZ36.png" alt="logo">
                    </div><!-- left menu --> 
                    
                    <div class="right-menu">
                        
                                   <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
                                <ul id="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">About ￬</a>
                                    <ul class="hidden">
                                        <li><a href="#">Who We Are</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Portfolio ￬</a>
                                    <ul class="hidden">
                                        <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Illustration</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            
                    </div><!-- right menu --> 
        </div><!-- Menu --> 

    </div><!-- head -->
```

Comment: first thing you should do is to learn bases of html and css. div element is an block element that means width is allways 100%, and if your div is 100% why you set margin: 0 auto; ??? as the css rule you set that all divs will have padding: 0; so why you set padding: 0; again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove position:absolute from your ul#menu and float it to the right.

So, just add this to your css:

```
ul#menu {
    position: static;
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Appears to work as intended if I knock the position:absolute off your UL and remove the fixed % width from the right-menu.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width: 1020px` from `.menu`

Change `.left-menu img` from `width:100%` to `width:130px`

Add `body {overflow:hidden;}`

Change `width: 70%;` in `.right-menu` to `width: 430px`

Answer (score -1):

Use twitter bootstrap . Check this http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.